# In MS SQL, how to combine varchar and seperate with comma (if both varchar exists)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hope you guys can help a bit. My challenge is simple but im not sure what way to solve it.
I have 2 varchar fields and I want to combine them AND seperate them with a comma if BOTH fields contains text. Both fields can be null, empty or with text inside.

```
Firstname | Last name | Result
   Not    |   Sure    | Not, Sure 
          |   Sure    | Sure
   Not    |           | Not 
  (null)  |   Sure    | Sure
   Not    |   (null)  | Not
  (null)  |   (null)  |
```

Comment: what version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something simple like this should work...

```
...
case 
   when FirstName IS NOT NULL and FirstName <> '' and LastName IS NOT NULL and LastName <> '' THEN CONCAT(FirstName, ', ',LastName)
   when FirstName = '' and LastName IS NOT NULL and LastName <> '' then LastName
   when LastName = '' and FirstName IS NOT NULL and FirstName <> '' then FirstName
   ELSE coalesce(FirstName, LastName)
end
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Some other databases have the convenient `concat_ws()` function for this.

You can set up a complicated `case`.  Here is a single expression that does what you want:

```
select replace(ltrim(rtrim(coalesce(firstname, '') + ' ' + coalesce(lastname, ''))), ' ', ', ')
```

The idea is that it puts a space between the two names (treating `NULL` values as empty strings).  Then it trims leading and trailing spaces, and replaces spaces with `', '`.

Note:  This assumes, as in your example, the you have no spaces in the names.

If they can have spaces, a `case` is a better bet:

```
select (case when firstname is null then coalesce(lastname, '')
             when lastname is null then firstname
             else firstname + ', ' + lastname
        end)
```

Comment: The 2nd option (case) is erroneous. If one of the names is an empty string and the other is a non-empty string the result is a non-empty string preceded/followed by coma.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz . . . I believe the answer explains that point.